# Sell my own NFT?

Tags: nft

On what platform can I sell my own NFT? I've seen NFT's kick-off recently. I have seen certain more exclusive platforms launch where large sales are being made, but have not seen one where anyone can startup and sell stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article is useful.](https://www.kapwing.com/resources/how-to-create-and-sell-nft-crypto-art/) Specifically [this platform](http://rarible.com) seems solid.

**Zora**

An piece sold by EDM artist Dillon Francis on Zora
Zora is a marketplace built firmly around the idea that content creators should take back control of their work from the major platforms. Zora allows creators to mint images, videos, audio files, and even plain text documents. The marketplace recently opened up and is now accessible to all creators. Zora is positioning itself as one of the coolest destinations for NFTs and is already collaborating with major music artists like Toro y Moi, Mura Masa, and Yaeji.

**Rarible**

The home screen of NFT Marketplace Rarible
A selection of works on the Rarible marketplace
Rarible is one of the most accessible sites for creators and collectors looking to get into NFTs. This was the first site I used when getting started, and the platform makes uploading your content and creating an NFT as simple as posting a YouTube video. In a market filled with invite-only sites, Rarible is one of the only NFT destinations that allows new creators to start selling work from the moment they sign up. This openness leads to a grab bag of material on the site and their moderation of copyrighted and offensive uploads needs some improvement. Sales for work on the site vary widely with pieces going for anywhere from a few dollars to tens of thousands.

**SuperRare**

The home screen of NFT Marketplace SuperRare
SuperRare gears itself toward digital artists
SuperRare prides itself on being the NFT marketplace for digital artists. You won't find memes, text posts, or simple sound effects for sale here. SuperRare's collection is highly curated and the team has intentionally been slow to onboard new creators to the platform. The result is browsing SuperRare feels like stepping into an elite digital gallery. The site has a stunning selection of NFTs reflecting thousands of hours of artist effort. Prices can get pretty steep and new creators only accepted with an application.

**Nifty Gateway**

The home screen of NFT Marketplace Nifty Gateway
Nifty Gateway focuses on daily NFT drops that promote fomo
Nifty Gateway is a highly curated NFT marketplace with a distinct focus on digital collectibles. Nifty works with high profile artists and musicians like Grimes and Justin Roiland to release collections of limited edition NFTs. Nifty Gateway is one the only major NFT sites that accepts credit cards setting it apart from every other digital retailer in this list. Similar to SuperRare, the art on Nifty is typically pretty expensive and new artists will have to apply before they can post work on the site.

**OpenSea**

The OpenSea homepage features works from major creators and small artists alike
OpenSea was one of the earliest NFT marketplaces established and features a massive library of content with prices across the board. The site deals in all kinds of NFTs ranging from digital art to 3D collectibles and items used in video games. OpenSea is also completely open to newcomers making it easy to get started here. The site is extremely accessible to those new to NFTs and has one of the best experiences for browsing pieces that I've seen from a major marketplace yet. OpenSea is also the first NFT marketplaces to openly experiment with a free creation system for creators.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/48604)

Comment: @clement check update.

Answer (score 2):

Opensea will probably be your best bet in trying to sell your already minted NFT. I highly recommend you check out this tutorial on how to mint an NFT: https://docs.alchemyapi.io/alchemy/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft

Comment: I agree. Best one.

Comment: @thesuperb1 how do we sell already mint NFT on other platforms like rarible and open sea?